# Google ClientLogin authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, google-api, google-authentication

I try make authentication using [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_settings_api_auth)

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Email", "testonly%2Ein%2E2011%40gmail%2Ecom");
connection.setRequestProperty("Passwd", "mypass");
connection.setRequestProperty("accountType", "HOSTED");
connection.setRequestProperty("service", "apps");
connection.connect();
```

But I get `Error=BadAuthentication`. How I should correct my code?

Comment: I run it at GAE platform, if it's matters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the proper `application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-type` and use the `OutputStream` to write the POST body.

```
//Open the Connection
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                                 "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Form the POST parameters
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
content.append("Email=").append(URLEncoder.encode(youremail, "UTF-8"));
content.append("&Passwd=").append(URLEncoder.encode(yourpassword, "UTF-8"));
content.append("&service=").append(URLEncoder.encode(yourapp, "UTF-8"));
OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(content.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
outputStream.close();

// Retrieve the output
int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
InputStream inputStream;
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
  inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
} else {
  inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
}
```

See [this](http://code.google.com/apis/base/samples/java/InsertExample.java) example to handle the result to get the `auth` token.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I will have possibility to check it only tomorrow.