# posting to blogger with Google-api-java-client

Tags: java, api, blogger

I am quite a beginner and learn at the moment "how to use apis properly": I imported the .jar files from code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client and added them via "external jar files" to the build path in eclipse.

The code snippet from https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/insert can't work standalone since OAuth2Native and BloggerScopes aren't recognized because one has to authenticate onself first. can someone help me with this, giving advice about how to authenticate oneself in the simplest possible way?

i already found this: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10

Comment: i found that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343277/google-clientlogin-authentication, but i have diffiulties to put those two together

Comment: Are you developing a web or a native application?

Comment: Applets are considered native applications, as they run on client side. OAuth2Native is only a sample implementation by Google for opening a browser and getting the redirected info back, that can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/shared/cmdline/oauth2/OAuth2Native.java?repo=samples&name=based-on-1.7&r=7063e615dbfcc8365c317bd19a338028dc507abe).

Comment: very good. oauth2native is clear now. i am still missing the BloggerScopes class, I googled for it without results

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217708/blogger-api-sample-code

Answer (score 1):

You can find Google's sample `OAuth2Native` implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/shared/cmdline/oauth2/OAuth2Native.java?repo=samples&name=based-on-1.9).

For the missing scope constant, just construct an array with the Blogger scope manually:

```
final static String[] Blogger = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger" };
```

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2015, There is no way to preauthorize someone for Blogger so I believe the only way to access Blogger Api is to generate access token through Auth 2 Playground ( https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ ) and then using the token for API call.